# Understanding the QED Lagrangian using Yang Mills formalism

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, yang-mills

In QED the Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i \not \partial - m ) \psi - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - e \bar{ \psi} \gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu
$$
which is the sum of a Dirac term, the Maxwell term and the interaction term.

In Yang-Mills theory the $\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} $ term is understood in terms of invariant quantities.

Given some principal bundle $(P, \pi, M)$, the Maxwell term is the trace of $F = dA$ where $A = \sigma^* \omega $ is the pull-back of a connection 1-f
orm $\omega$ along some local section $\sigma : U \subseteq M \rightarrow P$.

Is there a way to understand the Dirac term and the interaction term using this formalism?
Possibly in terms of some invariant quantities relevent to this principal bundle picture?

If there is, how does the gamma matrices (and Clifford algebra?) enter in this picture above?

Comment: You might want to look up the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/field%20%28physics%29) about fields